# Django proxy User model example

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add some custom logic to my Django User model and am trying to do so using a proxy User model.

I have a model something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CustomUser(User):
    def custom_method(self):
        return 'Something'

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

If I omit the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting then I'm able to run a Django shell and use CustomUser quite happily, however, I presumed I'd be able to set AUTH_USER_MODEL in my settings, so that this was the default user across my app (like when you use a totally custom user model), but this isn't the case, and when I try and run with AUTH_USER_MODEL set I get:

```
TypeError: CustomUser cannot proxy the swapped model 'myapp.CustomUser'
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You might as well use a completely custom user that inherits from AbstractUser. That has exactly the same functionality as what you're trying here.

Comment: I was only trying the proxy model as it was mentioned in the docs but your suggestion was worked great - thanks! :)

Comment: What @Ludo is trying to do is described in the docs. Inheriting from AbstractUser has implications for migrations and whatnot. He is not changing the database, so a proxy is the right decission. Why is a mechanism described in the docs not working? In my case I get the same error, but my structure is different: I have an myapp/models/custom_user.py, with a myapp/models/__init__.py where I import the CustomUser to make it available. How is `AUTH_USER_MODEL` finding the CustomUser class in this structure? I have found that you can not do `AUTH_USER_MODEL="myapp.models.CustomUser"`

Answer (score 6):

Setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to a custom class, and using a proxy model are two different approaches to customizing Django's User model behaviour. You're seeing that error because you're mixing them together, which doesn't make sense.

**Approach 1**:

If you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL='myapp.CustomUser'` then you shouldn't proxy anything. Define your custom user model like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

**Approach 2**:

Proxy the Django user model as you have above. Don't set `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. In your code, make sure you're always importing and using your `CustomUser` class.

---

Between the two approaches, #1 (custom model) is preferred if you're starting a new project because it gives you the most control. However, if you already have a running project migrating to a different model is a little tricky and so approach #2 (proxy model) might be the best you can do.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model for more details.